# can't serialize access for this transaction exception

Tags: java, database, serialization, isolation-level

I've a Java project which is successfully inserting n number of records in Database in Testing env but when i deployed it in Production machine, it fails with exception ***"can't serialize access exception for this transaction".***
I've searched on google and found that there might be other scripts running on Production machine which might be accessing the same table at that time.

> For this I've changed the isolation_level from
>   TRANSACTION_READ_COMMITTED to TRANSACTION_SERIALIZABLE.

Will it make any difference when deploy in Production machine.
Please assist.Thanks in advance